# Unusual compiler error in C++ program. Not syntax related. Windows programming

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile this program in C++ MSVS2010 and am getting odd compiler errors such as

```
 Error  12  error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   C:\Users\win7vm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WinDemo \Debug\WinDemo.exe    1.
```

and I'm also getting

```
 Error  11  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall Dice::returnRoll(void)" (?returnRoll@Dice@@QAEHXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Dice::drawSpots(struct HDC__ *,int,int,int,int,int,int,int)" (?drawSpots@Dice@@QAEXPAUHDC__@@HHHHHHH@Z)    C:\Users\win7vm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WinDemo \WinDemo \Debug\WinDemo.exe   1\Dice.obj
```

Neither of which seem to be syntax related and I'm not fully understanding them.
Basically, the idea is to get the switch statement to display the value passed into that function from the other function.  I'm almost certain that it is a simple reference/pointer issue that I'm just completely missing.  There's a header with this class, a windows.h (out-of-the-box unmodified so you can look it up if you need to), and functions with a main file (functions and class included here). Let me pre-answer 2 questions that will almost certainly come up: a) yes, it absolutely has to use the windows.h file in c++.  b) yes, I'm aware that there are a hundred better libraries and languages to use for this problem, I have no choice in the matter here.  Someone may also try to point out the global variables declared.  The globals were a temporary but necessary inconvenience while troubleshooting a relatively short block of code.  I realize that many of you are extremely skilled in C++ but I am asking for your patience to explain your answers with my lower-level of C++ programming in mind.  Thank you. :)

**
//header file

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int count=0;
int *result = &count;

class Dice
{
public:
    void drawSpots(HDC hdc, int x1,int y1, int x2,int y2, int r, int g,int b);
    int roll();
    wchar_t * drawString();
    int returnRoll();
private:
    int x1,x2,y1,y2,sr,sg,sb;
    //int &count;
    //int *result;
    int value;
    int spotColor;
};


//definitions file


void Dice::drawSpots(HDC hdc, int x1,int y1, int x2,int y2, int r, int g,int b)
{
    *result = roll();
    //vectorOfDice.push_back(result);
    //wchar_t * drawString();
    returnRoll();
    HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(r,g,b));
    SelectObject(hdc,hBrush);
    switch(*result)
    {
    case 1:
        //draw something based on case
        break;
    case 2:
        //draw something based on case
        break;
    case 3:
        //draw something based on case
        break;
    case 4:
        //draw something based on case
        break;
    case 5:
        //draw something based on case      
                    break;
    case 6:
        //draw something based on case      
                    break;
    }

    DeleteObject(hBrush);
}

int Dice::roll()
{
    value=1+(rand()%6);
    return value;
}


int Dice::returnRoll()
{
    count=0;
    if((*result == 2)||(*result == 4)||(*result == 6))
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

wchar_t * Dice::drawString()
{
    //result = returnRoll(result);
    //result = roll();
    switch(*result)
    {
    case 0:
        return L"no";
        break;
    case 1:
        return L"1";
        break;
    case 2:
        return L"2";
        break;
    case 3:
        return L"3";
        break;
    case 4:
        return L"4";
        break;
    case 5:
        return L"5";
        break;
    case 6:
        return L"6";
        break;
    }
    return L"X";
}


//main file


#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "Dice.h"


const wchar_t g_szClassName[] = L"myWindowClass";



// Step 4: the Window Procedure
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Dice dice;

    //state variables
    static int red = 0;
    static int green = 0;
    static int blue = 100;

    static int tr = 0;
    static int tg = 0;
    static int tb = 0;

    HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
    HPEN hPen1;
    HPEN hPen2;


    HBRUSH hBrush1;
    HFONT hFont1;
    RECT rect;
    int fontHeight = 100;


    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hDC = BeginPaint(hwnd,&Ps);

            hPen1=CreatePen(PS_SOLID,5,RGB(red,green,blue));
            hPen2=CreatePen(PS_SOLID,5,RGB(0,0,0));

            hBrush1= CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,255));

            SelectObject(hDC,hPen1);
            SelectObject(hDC,hBrush1);

            fontHeight=50;
            hFont1=CreateFont(fontHeight,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,L"Times New Roman");
            //hFont1=CreateFont(fontHeight,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,L"Arial");
            SelectObject(hDC,hFont1);

            rect.top=100;
            rect.bottom=700;
            rect.left = 550;
            rect.right =950;

            DrawText(hDC,L"There are ",-1,&rect,DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK );
            rect.top=200;
            DrawText(hDC,dice.drawString(),-1,&rect,DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK );
            rect.top=300;
            DrawText(hDC,L" even dice!",-1,&rect,DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK );


            DeleteObject(hBrush1);
            DeleteObject(hPen2);
            DeleteObject(hPen1);
            EndPaint(hwnd,&Ps);
        break;
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
            if(wParam==VK_SPACE)
            {
                dice.roll();
                InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,true);
            }
            break;
        case WM_CHAR:
            if(wParam=='c')
            {
                tr=rand()%256;
                tg=rand()%256;
                tb=rand()%256;
                dice.spotColors();
            }
            InvalidateRect(hwnd,NULL,true);
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Step 2: Creating the Window
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
        g_szClassName,
        L"window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1000, 800,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Window Creation Failed!", L"Error!",
            MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

**

Edit: 
Yes thanks I'm getting linker errors, but adding Dice:: to signature (seemed to reduce the compiler complaining but) still I'm getting similar unusual errors such as --

```
Error   11  error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found   C:\Users\win7vm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\\WinDemo \Debug\WinDemo.exe   1

Error   10  error LNK2005: "int * result" (?result@@3PAHA) already defined in Dice.obj  C:\Users\win7vm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WinDemo \WinDemo \main.obj

Error   9   error LNK2005: "int count" (?count@@3HA) already defined in Dice.obj    C:\Users\win7vm\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WinDemo \WinDemo \main.obj
```

Comment: Common people why the downvotes. Just because you think the answer is trivial does not mean it is for new people. You should be encouraging beginners not being unpleasant about it.

Comment: Actually I solved it myself. I defined the count variables again in my functions file and (not in main) and it compiled. Never ran into that before, and it seems like it has something to do with the windows.h as one of the header files (from my own research and also from advice from a programmer who said he's worked with it) and the way variables are defined in different files but not linked properly.

Answer (score 8):

You didn't put `Dice::` in the signature of your `returnRoll` definition. This causes the linker to never find it when it needs to, and therefore give you a linker error (not a compiler error).

```
int Dice::returnRoll() {...}
    ^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `Dice::` in returnRoll definition.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to make returnRoll part of Dice::

You are simply missing the Dice::

```
int Dice::roll()
{
    value=1+(rand()%6);
    return value;
}


int returnRoll()
{
    count=0;
    if((*result == 2)||(*result == 4)||(*result == 6))
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your new problem, I'm guessing that you didn't mention that you included the header file in both of the files not just the main file. You shouldn't define global variables in header files or you get problems like this. You need to move the definitions for count and result to the source file instead of the header. I don't see you using them in the main file but if you are you need to add

```
extern int count;
extern int* result;
```

to the header file.

Better yet would be to avoid using global variables, this isn't a situation where you need them. Instead of having drawSpots set a global variable, why not just return the value?